# WebWorker: Is onerror called for all kinds of errors?

Tags: javascript, web-worker

I'm wondering if `worker.onerror` is called for all kinds of errors.

Currently I have a situation where the Worker is terminated in the middle of a loop and I'm unable to find the reason because there is no error message at all. No exception, no message on the console. In Chrome debugger I can see that the node for the WebWorker is also removed from the sources pane.

Are there more ways to catch an error from a WebWorker?

edit::
Strangely that error-situation does not appear in Safari, only in Chrome... 
The worker is not terminated in Safari... maybe It's a browser bug...

Comment: It might not be a bad idea to use lots of `try {} catch(e) { console.error('(in web worker)', e) }`s in your program?

Comment: I already tried to set a try/catch around the area where the error appears, but it does not react... I'm 100% sure that the try/catch is correct... so there must be something special...

Comment: Can you post some of the worker code where you suspect the error is occurring?  {{worker.onerror}} is meant to be called for all types of errors, though it can be difficult to reason about.

Comment: Without actual test code, this question is useless. Try make separate test-case to reproduce the problem. Most likely you will then find whether it's a bug or not. Trust me, making separate testcases IS worth the time and effort.

Comment: Just to make it clear: I did not ask this question in the hope that anybody could tell me the reason for the error. I just wanted to know if there are more ways to catch an error-_message_ then just onerror().